# Accessing scope inside nested child scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

data here is an array of objects with properties {name:"xx",value:1}
  I want to fill the column array with the data

```
 function sampleModel(data)
{
   this.columns=[];
   $.each(data,function(key,value){
        //how do i fill in the column array with key.name property
    });
}
```

Comment: $.each(data,function(key,value){
        this.columns.push(key.name);
    });     this gives me an error that this.columns is not defined

Comment: what _this_ you expect here `this.columns=[];`? _this_ inside `each` function refers to same as `value` parameter

Answer (score 3):

Use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method:

```
function sampleModel(data) {
    this.columns = data.map(function(obj) {
        return obj.name;
    });
}
```

Comment: @OP This is the correct way of doing what you wanted to do.

Comment: @AnishAravind, are you sure that _data_ is `array`?

Comment: @AnishAravind, in this case `data` have _map_, if in your case - not, so you try get wrong method, or try get method from wrong object

Comment: @AnishAravind, can you provide plnkr or jsfiddle that can reproduce your error?

Comment: @AnishAravind What does `console.log(data)` output?

Comment: What is that `data`? It's not an array so don't use array methods on it. Just check `console.log(data)`.

Comment: {name:"xx",value:1},{name:"yy",value:2},{name:"zz",value:3}...data looks somewhat like this..it is an array of objects..

Comment: If it was an array than my answer would work. If it doesn't, it means that `data` is not an array. What is `console.log(typeof data)`? (I guess "string").

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [for..in loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) for cycle through elements, and use the [array push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) for collect data

```
function sampleModel(data)
{
   this.columns=[];
   for(var key in data)
      this.columns.push(data[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  `$scope.column.push(item);`

```
angular.forEach(data,function(item) {
     $scope.column.push(item);
});
```

Hopefully this will work

Or

```
 function sampleModel(data)
{
   $scope.columns=[];
   angular.foreach(data,function(value){
        //how do i fill in the column array with key.name property
    $scope.column.push(value);
    });
}
```